# Populating unexported fields

Tags: go, retry-logic

I'm using this retry logic with a stop
https://upgear.io/blog/simple-golang-retry-function/

My code looks like this

```
type Stop struct {
    error
}

...
if s, ok := err.(Stop); ok {
   return s.error
}
...
```

I'm trying to get the Stop functionality to work outside the namespace, so I'm doing this

```
...
return lib.Stop{errors.New("this is an error")}
...
```

But I'm getting a complication error:

```
implicit assignment to unexported field error in struct literal of type lib.Stop
```

How would I populate the Stop with the error when its unexported?

I was thinking that I need change the struct to `Error error` but then it doesnt work with the `err.(Stop)`

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change it to a named field `Err error` and then explicitly add the `Error() string` method to make `Stop` implement `error`:

```
type Stop struct {
    Msg error
}

func (s Stop) Error() string {
    return s.Msg.Error()
}
```

Alternatively, you could just create a "constructor" func for `Stop` (which is the general approach for letting outside callers instantiate a struct with unexported fields):

```
type Stop struct {
    error
}

func NewStop(err error) Stop {
    return Stop{err}
}
```